# Merge/flatten an array of arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataset

I Have this Multi-dimensional Array Currently

```
[array([['Alpha', 100],
       ['Alpha', 100],
       ['Alpha', 200]], dtype=object), 
array([['Alpha', 'A1'],
       ['Alpha', 'A1'],
       ['Alpha', 'A2']], dtype=object), 
array([[100, 'A1'],
       [100, 'A1'],
       [200, 'A2']], dtype=object), 
array([['Alpha', 100, 'A1'],
       ['Alpha', 100, 'A1'],
       ['Alpha', 200, 'A2']], dtype=object)]
```

I would like to condense duplicate arrays within the array and show how many were condensed into one. So it should like something like this:

```
(2) ALPHA 100
(1) ALPHA 200

(2) ALPHA A1
(1) ALPHA A2

(2) 100 A1
(1) 200 A2

(2) ALPHA 100 A1
(1) ALPHA 200 A2
```

Comment: you can use `np.unique` with `return_counts = True`

Comment: How would that look in a loop?

Comment: this is not an array of arrays / multidimensional array, this is a `list` with `numpy.ndarray` objects inside of it

Comment: how do you convert the list to an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [['Alpha', 100],['Alpha', 100],['Alpha', 200], 
     ['Alpha', 'A1'],['Alpha', 'A1'],['Alpha', 'A2'],
     [100, 'A1'],[100, 'A1'],[200, 'A2'],
     ['Alpha', 100, 'A1'], ['Alpha', 200, 'A2']]

result = []

for x in C:
    if x not in result:
        result.append(x)
print (result)
```

Output:

```
[['Alpha', 100], ['Alpha', 200], ['Alpha', 'A1'], ['Alpha', 'A2'], [100, 'A1'], [200, 'A2'], ['Alpha', 100, 'A1'], ['Alpha', 200, 'A2']]
```